# Unable to create a versioned API in SailJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, sails.js

First things first, version of various dependencies
**Ubuntu** - 15.04
**NodeJS** - 6.10.3
**NPM** - 3.10.10
**Sails** - 0.12.13

Second, here's what I did:
1. Installed Sails globally
2. In the directory `/var/www`, ran the command `sails new app`
3. Created a file `UserController.js` in `api/controllers/v1`
4. Created a file `User.js` in `api/models`

Code for **UserController.js**

```
module.exports = {

  findOne: function(req, res) {

    return res.send("Hello World!!! User -> findOne");
  },

  login: function(req, res) {

    return res.send("Hello World!!! User -> login");
  }
}
```

Code for **User.js**

```
module.exports = {}
```

Now, when I start my server using `sails lift`, here's what happens:

- Browse http://localhost:1337/v1/user/1 - Page Not Found (404)
- Browse http://localhost:1337/v1/user/login

  > Hello World!!! User -> Login

---

I know I'm going to sound silly, but I thought it is probably because I didn't use the *Generator* feature of Sails. So, here's what I did next: `sails generate api v1/Product`. And the file structure after this command is like this:

```
api  
|-- controllers  
    |-- v1  
        |-- UserController.js
    |-- V1  
        |-- ProductController.js
|-- models  
    |-- User.js  
    |-- V1  
        |-- Product.js
```

I wrote similar code in `ProductController.js` as I did in `UserController.js` and I expected that now the Product API should work but the result was same as in case of `/v1/user/1`.

---

As per the SailJS [Blueprint API](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api), this should have worked. So, can anyone explain why this is happening and how can I make **`/v1/user/1`** and **`/v1/user/login`** both work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of ways to achieve this. The first option is to set the `restPrefix` to `/v1` inside `config/blueprints.js`

> An optional mount path for all REST blueprint routes on a controller and it does not include `actions` and `shortcuts` routes. 
>   This allows you to take advantage of REST blueprint routing even if you need to namespace your RESTful API methods

Now with same directory structure i.e., `/controllers/v1/UserController.js` and `/models/User.js`, you should be able to access both the `/login` and `findOne` methods.

The second option is to set the `prefix` to `/v1` inside `config/blueprints.js`

> An optional mount path for all blueprint routes on a controller, including `rest`, `actions`, and `shortcuts`. 
>   This allows you to take advantage of blueprint routing, even if you need to namespace your API methods.
>   (NOTE: This only applies to blueprint autoroutes, not manual routes from `sails.config.routes`)

Now the directory structure would be `/controllers/UserController.js` and `/models/User.js`. You have the mapping `/v1` setup for you.

On the other hand, you can completely turn off blueprint routes and set up your own routes inside `/config/routes.js`. This would give you more flexibility and you can also have `environment` specific routes inside `config/env/[your_env].js`

Comment: Both the methods are valid, but if I want to run two API's `/v1/user/1` and `v2/user/1`, the first two methods won't work. Also, if the number of API's are in 100's the third method becomes unscalable.

Comment: Agreed, which is why it always better to manually configure routes inside the `config/routes.js`. If your `api` has 100 methods, then the `api` in itself becomes difficult to handle.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't agree that configuring each and every route in `config/routes.js` is the best and most optimal way to approach the problem. Thanks for the reply though

Comment: Don't be. Personally, I have seen large production systems working without any issues. I would be glad if someone posts a better method!